# how to pass value into boost option parameter of code from qsub

Tags: c++, boost, parallel-processing, multicore, qsub

I have a program that takes some value from user (parameter is passed using boost option). 
./prog --my-value 32

Its fine till here, but now I am running the program in multi nodes and multi cores using qsub script(and I am allowed to use pbs script only)
and want to pass the argument.
qsub ./xyz.sh --my-value 32  [ how could I do this .. I mean can I do this somehow ? ]

Comment: Its simple, in the qsub script after you specify your executable, pbsdsh - u -v ... --my-value 32 . it was that simple

Comment: Make your comment an answer, StackOverflow encourages that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple, in the pbs script after you specify your executable,
APP_PATH= /.. (what ever app)
APP_OPTION = (what ever goes here)
pbsdsh - u -v ... --my-value 32